# "String does not match the pattern of \"^(?:@[a-z0-9-*~][a-z0-9-*._~]*/)?[a-z0-9-~][a-z0-9-._~]*$\"."

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, discord, bots

So I Recently Got A New CPU... because the old one kept making weird noises when it was booting up windows, but all the data on Local Disk C: got erased, including my discord bot file, i built a new one with same token, i was making my package.json and all of a sudden there was a problem with the `"name"` property, it said
`String does not match the pattern of \"^(?:@[a-z0-9-*~][a-z0-9-*._~]*/)?[a-z0-9-~][a-z0-9-._~]*$\".`,
here's the code in the package.json :

```
{
    "name": "Zuno",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "My First Discord Bot.",
    "main": "bot.js",
    "author": "Luxof",
    "dependencies": {}
}
```

when i got a new CPU it was 32-bit, (i feel uncomfortable even thinking that my computer is 32-bit) so i don't know if my computer just went retard mode or it's because my computer is 32 bit, i double-checked what was on the website (https://www.digitaltrends.com/gaming/how-to-make-a-discord-bot/) and i did exactly correct, what do i do? i'm running Visual Studio Code.

Comment: that doesn't seem to be a valid javascript regex - which language is that regex from (looks like python)

Comment: seems the `Z` is the problem - looks like no capitals allowed

Comment: Jaromanda X i switched over to Discord.py. Thanks Anyway Tho!